# Why cannot I use @ConfigurationProperties instead of @Value in Spring WebConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-config

I want to configure my WebConfig bean to have different CORS origin depending on the profile`application.properties`.

For some reason the value in my `application-local.properties` is not injected into the field of my WebConfig bean.

When I use `@Value` here it will work (please check last headline for the working example)

### Entry Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@ComponentScan("com.company.coma")
public class EventWebApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EventWebApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

### WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("coma.cors")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  private String origin;

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping(Resources.Services.APIs.Event.GET_STATUS + "/**")
            .allowedOrigins(origin);
  }
}
```

### application-local.properties

```
coma.cors.origin=http://localhost:8080
```

### Execution

starting the application with `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`

### Result

[image]

### Working example

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Value("${coma.cors.origin}") // this works
  private String origin;

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping(Resources.Services.APIs.Event.GET_STATUS + "/**")
            .allowedOrigins(origin);
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use `@Value` there?

Comment: I'm trying at the moment - but that wouldn't make sense because both approache use the same mechanics don't they?

Comment: @Janar ok it worked... I need to reform my question therefore

Comment: Will putting the value in String quotes help? `coma.cors.origin="http://localhost:8080"`